# SSH server grinding to a halt when users grep large files - high NET_RX and high softirqs - How to limit?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, performance, nfs

I have a server running fedora 14 - Linux-2.6.35 with a 1Gbps NIC. It has NFSv3 mounts supplied by an Isilon server.

It freezes whenever any user works with a large file(grep or similar) that exists on the NFS server. I could clearly see that just before the server freeze,

1. The network usage hits close to 1 Gbps,
2. interupts from NET_RX overwhelms the cpu cores, and
3. High amounts of soft_irqs.

Any ideas to approach these stalls?

ifconfig on the NIC shows

```
[root@interactive ~]# ifconfig eth1 <redacted>
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet addr:xx.yy.zz.aa  Bcast:A.B.C.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: aaaa::bbb:ccc:ddd:eee/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:685902495 errors:6256 dropped:28226 overruns:0 frame:6256
      TX packets:661268729 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:973006411081 (906.1 GiB)  TX bytes:146154890021 (136.1 GiB)
      Interrupt:19 Memory:d8000000-d8012800
```

Are the Errors too high?

Is there a way to limit a SSH user's capability to saturate the network interface?

Comment: F14 is out of support for more than 6 years now.

Comment: @Sven I'm furious that I'm being pushed to touch/maintain this unsupported OS. But, I inherited it, and cannot replace it with modern hardware/OS until the new hardware arrives.

Comment: You could switch to tcp for the NFS mount, it will be less likely to saturate your network bandwidth. If you really would want to Limit specific (ssh) users a cgroup would be needed, not sure if such an old distribution has all the required features

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution would be to increase the bandwidth available to the server. You can upgrade to 10G connectivity or you can add additional NICs on the server and team them (etherchannel).

Also, as Sven commented above, you will need to make sure you have the latest drivers for you NIC and upgrade Operating System if needed.

To limit ssh user's capability, you can try Quality of Service (Traffic Control). You can find more about by searching for 'tc' command.

Answer (score 0):

The network is going to go up because whatever (grep, etc) has to read the file.  What I would try would be:

Upgrade to a version from **this DECADE** - I know, you're stuck.

Try the same thing via console - I bet this is not SSH

Is there anything in the logs (i.e. /var/log/messages, dmesg) like CPU stuck or NFS server not responding?

Wireshark the for fragmented packets, etc

Change the nfs client mount options:  hard vs soft, wsize, rsize, timeo and retrans, UDP vs TCP

Lower the MTU on both devices